# Can I only log when some variable is set to true in python?

Tags: python

I want my code to only log debug level messages when some variable is set to true. Is it possible? Here is my config for the logging module. Right now, I have to comment and uncomment at different places in my code to enable or disable the logging...

```
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s; %(levelname)s;\t %(message)s')
handler = logging.FileHandler('/mylog.log')
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger = logging.getLogger('')
logger.addHandler(handler)
logger.setLevel('DEBUG')

<then somewhere in my code>
logger.debug('some messages')
```

It would be even better if this variable can be an integer, and when set, only logger with level same or higher will function... Is it possible?

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like what logger levels are for.

Answer (score 1):

`if my_var: logger.setLevel('Warning')` [check the doc](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html)

Comment: Works great thank you!